# SQL - Custom Column to Fill with values from 2 columns using an OR statement

Tags: sql, metabase

This is the lo-fi current version of the table

| ID | Custom column | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | X |  |
| 2 |  |  | Y |

Want to populate the custom column with either X or Y as such:

| ID | Custom column | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | X |  |
| 2 | Y |  | Y |

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL - please correct your tags.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate the values as in the example below:

```
SELECT 
    Title, 
    FirstName, 
    MiddleName, 
    LastName,
    Title + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName as MailingName
FROM Person.Person
```

Example taken from: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2985/concatenate-sql-server-columns-into-a-string-with-concat/

If you need it to be other type than a string you can always cast it to the proper type.

Answer (score 0):

As a `select`, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(value, value2) as custom_column
from t;
```

As an `update`:

```
update t
    set custom_column = coalesce(value, value2);
```